# Find all triples of non-negative Integers $a,b,c$ such that $a!b!=a!+b!+c!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

Exactly what it says in the Title;  not much development from there :/

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How can you determine that $b>a$, when your equation is symmetric in $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Maybe OP determined that $a \not= b$, and then wlog $b > a$.  It would be a non-trivial finding. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung, but it would also be a *wrong* finding....

Comment: Ignore that then, I am truly stumped

Comment: @BarryCipra: Ha ha, yeah, just noticed that. :-)

Comment: See "Factorial Problems" [here](http://mathschallenge.net/problems/pdfs/mathschallenge_3_star.pdf), Problem ID: 216 (09 Mar 2005).

Comment: @DietrichBurde unable to find it. I downloaded as a pdf, got 142 pages. What pages are involved?

Comment: This problem is also discussed on Ask Dr. Math [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65132.html).

Comment: @DietrichBurde that worked, for me it says page 36

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you've determined that without loss of generality $b\geq a$. We then have $$b!=1+\frac{b!}{a!}+\frac{c!}{a!},\,c\geq a.$$ Since $a!b!>a!+b!$, we have $a!,\,b!\geq 2$ so $b\geq a\geq 2$. In fact if $a=2$ then $2\times b! = 2+b!+c!,\,b!=2+c!$, which has no solutions. So $b\geq a\geq 3$ and $3|b!$, so $\frac{b!}{a!},\,\frac{c!}{a!}$ are not both multiples of $3$, and $b,\,c$ are not both $\geq a+3$. But $a!=1+\frac{a!}{b!}+\frac{c!}{b!}$, so either $a=b\leq c$ or $a<b>c$. The latter case precludes $c\geq a+3$, and so does the former since $\frac{c!}{a!}=a!-2\notin 3\mathbb{Z}$. So $c\in \left\{a,\,a+1,\,a+2\right\}$.

Case I: $c=a$ so $3|b!=2+\frac{b!}{a!}$ so $b\geq a+2$. If $b=a$ then $a!=3$; if $b=a+1$ then $\left(a+1\right)!=a+3$; if $b=a+2$ then $\left(a+2\right)!=a^2+3a+4$. One can easily check none of these is solved by integers $a \geq 3$.

Case II: $c=a+1$ so $b!=a+2+\frac{b!}{a!}$ and $a!-1|b!-\frac{b!}{a!}=a+2$. Since $a!-1 > a+2$  for $a\geq 4$ we have $a=3,\,c=4$, giving one solution with $b=3$. It turns out there are no others (see the next paragraph).

Case III: $c=a+2$ so $b!=a^2+3a+3+\frac{b!}{a!}$, so $a!-1|a^2+3a+3$, which is consistent with neither $a=3$ nor $a=4$. But $a!-1>a^2+3a+3$ whenever $a\geq 5$, so there are no more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First assume $a = b,$ so the equation becomes $a!(a!-2) = c!.$  In particular this implies that $a!-2 = 0$ or $(a+1)\cdots(a+k)$ for some $k > 0.$ The first case is impossible, and in the second, either $a+1\mid a!$ or $a!\equiv -1\mod (a+1)$ and $a+1$ is prime (Wilson's theorem). Actually there is a remaining case, in which $a! - 2 = a+1,$ which is when $a = b =3,$ giving a solution with $c = 4.$ Evidently when $a > 3,$ this is no longer possible, so we reduce to the cases above.

If $a+1\mid a!,$ then $a+1$ does not divide $a!-2$ unless $a+1\mid 2,$ whence $a = 1$ or $0.$ This is impossible, so $a+1$ is prime and $a! - 2\equiv -3\mod (a+1).$ But $a+1\mid a! - 2,$ so $a+1 = 3\Rightarrow a = b = 2,$ which again is impossible. Hence $a\not= b.$

Without loss of generality let $1 < a < b.$ Note then that $c > b,$ since $b!\mid RHS \Rightarrow b! \mid a! + c! < b! + c!.$ Divide through by $a!$ to get 
$$b! = 1 + b!/a! + c!/a!.$$
Then mod $a+1,$ the LHS is $0,$ while the RHS is $1,$ so the only solution is $(a,b,c) = (3,3,4).$