# All elements of this finite abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 &2&2\\3&4&2 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ generated by the vectors $\vec{g_i} = \sum_{j=1}^3 a_{ji}\vec{e_j}$ using $A = \|a_{ji}\|$.

Describe all elements of finite order in the factorgroup $\mathbb{Z}^3/H$ in terms of the compliment $\mathbb{Z}^3 \setminus H$

---

Now there's a theorem that says that $|\mathbb{Z}^3/H|=\det(A)=4$. So there are $4$ elements to be found.

$$\vec{g_1} = (5\space 0\space 0) \quad \vec{g_2} = (0\space 6 \space0) \quad \vec{g_3} = (0\space 0\space 9)$$

are the generating vectors of $H$.

So now elements of finite order:

$$\vec{h_1} = (1\space 0\space 0) \quad \vec{h_2} = (0\space 1 \space0) \quad \vec{h_3} = (0\space 0\space 1) $$
Questions:

1. What is the fourth element with finite order?
2. How do you write them in terms of the complement?

Comment: Aren't your $\vec{g_i}$ simply the column vectors for $A$, or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @ThomasRasberry the basis of an integral lattice is often given as either the column or rows of a matrix, and I believe that applies here. Nice to know the source of the problem...

Comment: @ThomasRasberry I find the notation confusing but it seems like gi is the sum of the j'th row multiplied by the j-th basis vector. Does that make sense?

Comment: Again, source of the problem?

Comment: @will-jagy What do you mean? I do not know how to complete the question.

Comment: Yes, this is probably notational confusion on my part. I am used to $a_{ji}$ meaning the element in row $j$, column$i$, which would indicate the sum is over the three unit vectors, each multiplied by their corresponding row element in column $i$, hence would simply just be column $i$ for a particular $g_i$.

Comment: I mean, in what book did you find this question? What else is in the chapter containing this problem?

Comment: @will-jagy It's a past exam for intro to group theory. The prof said that the way to solve it was to use a theory from the "finite abelian groups" which I used above to figure out that there are 4 finite order elements in H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H$ is called an integral lattice. The columns of $A$ are the basis. All elements of $H$ are column vectors of integers
$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right)
$$
such that $x \equiv z \pmod 2$ and $y \equiv 0 \pmod 2. $ It takes a little matrix nonsense to confirm that any such vector $X$ really can be written as an integer linear combination of the columns of $A.$ Once you know that much, the cosets are
$$
H +
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right) = H
$$

$$
H +
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
H +
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
H +
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so the quotient is the Klein four-group.

Meanwhile,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 2\\
3 & 4 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-U + 2 V \\
U - 2 V + W \\
V - W
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
U \\
2 V \\
U + 2 W
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: How are those elements finite order though?

Comment: @15yyyy .I'm lost at sea. If $H$ is the subgroup of $Z^3$ generated by $g_1,g_2,g_3$ then$ H=\{(a,b,c) :5|a\land 6|b \land 9|c\}.$  And $(x,y,z)+H=(x',y',z')+H\iff [5|(x-x')\land 6|(y-y')\land 9| (z-z')].$ This gives 270 cosets.